# `latomic` flag sometimes not required?

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic, stdatomic

I know that the `-latomic` flag is required for the `atomic` library to be linked in by GCC. However, for some reason `std::atomic<int>` doesn't require it to build

[build without latomic](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++std::atomic%3Cint%3E+atomicData%7B5%7D%3B%0A++++auto+newData+%3D+atomicData.load()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

while structs do

[build requires latomic](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:27,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:27,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:27,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:27),source:%27%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0A//+packed+struct+definition%0A%23pragma+pack(push,+1)%0Astruct+PropBoardSensorData+%7B%0A++++PropBoardSensorData()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++uint32_t+timestamp%3B%0A++++int32_t+adc0,+adc1,+adc2,+adc3,+adc4,+adc5,+adc6,+adc7,+adc8,+adc9,+adc10,+adc11,+adc12,+adc13,+adc14%3B%0A++++int32_t+loadCellRaw%3B%0A++++float+tcInternalTemp%3B%0A++++float+tcTemp1,+tcTemp2,+tcTemp3,+tcTemp4%3B%0A++++//+fault+flags+is+a+bitfield+%5Bfault,+open,+gnd,+vcc%5D+from+LSB+to+MSB+for+each+tc+reader,+1+meaning+that+fault+is+active%0A++++uint8_t+tcFaultFlags%5B4%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%23pragma+pack(pop)%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++PropBoardSensorData+data%7B%7D%3B%0A++++data.adc10+%3D+5%3B%0A%0A++++std::atomic%3CPropBoardSensorData%3E+atomicData%7Bdata%7D%3B%0A++++auto+newData+%3D+atomicData.load()%3B%0A%0A++++std::atomic%3CPropBoardSensorData%3E+defaultAtom%7BPropBoardSensorData%7B%7D%7D%3B%0A++++auto+newData2+%3D+defaultAtom.load()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

what is this difference caused by?

Comment: Please post the code and the errors in the question in form of a [mcve].

Comment: @273K all of my examples are linked through Godbolt and are minimally reproducible.

Comment: A plausible explanation is that on your target architecture, atomic operations on int-sized operands are directly mapped onto processor instructions (via intrinsics) and don't need any library code.

Comment: External links are not searchable on SO, the second code can be reduced to a few lines `#include <atomic>

struct PropBoardSensorData {
    float tcTemp1, tcTemp2, tcTemp3;
};

int main(){
    std::atomic<PropBoardSensorData> atomicData{};
    auto newData = atomicData.load();
}`

Comment: @273K "_External links are not searchable on SO_" Ironically, the external link does contain the code, so the posted message w/ just links is no shorter than one with full code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the compiler inlines the `__atomic` builtins that `std::atomic` uses, the object file won't contain any references to functions that `libatomic` defines.

This is normal for most architectures with `atomic<size_t>` or smaller, at least with optimization enabled, and sometimes for structs the size of two pointers on some architectures.  (But not x86-64 since GCC7, where it chooses not to inline `lock cmpxchg16b` even if you compile with `-mcx16`, and chooses not to report it as `is_lock_free`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html)

In your case, as you can see by mousing over the source and looking at the asm,  `auto newData = atomicData.load();` compiled to `mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax` even in your debug built.  (With a huge amount of clutter since you disabled optimization.)